# MySQL Stored Procedure strange behavior PHP

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

This is my MySQL Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'c4_awuser'@'%'
PROCEDURE c4_awdb.aw_spZAAAOttieniDataTables(IN _identificativoTabella VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN

  DECLARE finito INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE nomeColonna VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT '';
  DECLARE titoloColonna VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT '';
  DECLARE queryColonne LONGTEXT DEFAULT 'SELECT ';
  DECLARE _nomeVista VARCHAR(255);
  DECLARE curColonne CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
      COLUMN_NAME,
      COALESCE(nome_campo, COLUMN_NAME) AS nome_campo
    FROM information_schema.columns
      LEFT JOIN aw_tbZAAEGestioneTabelleDati
        ON ZAAEcvVistaAssociata = _nomeVista
      LEFT JOIN aw_tbZAACCampi
        ON nome_campo_db = COLUMN_NAME
        AND tabella = ZAAEcvNomeTabella
    WHERE table_name = _nomeVista;

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finito = 1;

  SELECT
    ZAAEcvVistaAssociata INTO _nomeVista
  FROM aw_tbZAAEGestioneTabelleDati
  WHERE ZAAEcvIdentificativoTabella = _identificativoTabella;

  IF _nomeVista IS NOT NULL AND EXISTS (SELECT
    DISTINCT 1
      FROM information_schema.columns
      WHERE table_name = _nomeVista) THEN

    OPEN curColonne;
 
    ciclaColonne: LOOP
        FETCH curColonne INTO nomeColonna,titoloColonna;
        IF finito = 1 THEN 
          LEAVE ciclaColonne;
        END IF;
        
        SET queryColonne = CONCAT(queryColonne,nomeColonna,' AS \'',titoloColonna,'\',');
        
    END LOOP ciclaColonne;

    CLOSE curColonne;
    
    IF RIGHT(queryColonne,1) = ',' THEN
        SET queryColonne = LEFT(queryColonne,LENGTH(queryColonne)-1);
    END IF;
    
    SET queryColonne = CONCAT(queryColonne,' FROM ',_nomeVista);

    SET @sql = queryColonne;
    PREPARE dynamic_statement FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE dynamic_statement;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE dynamic_statement;

  END IF;
    
END
```

Are there any error?
If I execute this in MySQL client it gives me 2 record (correct), but if I execute this from PHP it gives me 0 record, but no error.
I pass as parameter an id such as 'elenco_corsi'. I search in aw_tbZAAEGestioneTabelleDati what is his view, then I use system table to get view's field, the i build a query and execute it via statement.

---

#### UPDATE

How I invoke procedure from PHP.
(`require DB();` define `$conn`)

```
require DB();
$id_datatable = "elenco_corsi";
$stmt = $conn->prepare("CALL aw_spZAAAOttieniDataTables(?);");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $id_datatable);
if($stmt->execute()) {
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();

    echo "<br />Numero righe: ".$result->num_rows."<br /><br />";

    if($result && $result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "yes";
            $dati[] = $row;
        }
        $resp = new stdClass();
        $resp->esito = 1;
        $resp->dati = $dati;
    } else {
        // it enter here
        $resp = new stdClass();
        $resp->esito = 20;
        $resp->dati = $dati;
    }
} else {
    $resp = new stdClass();
    $resp->esito = 30;
    $resp->dati = $dati;
}
```

Comment: If the query works in the MySQL client, but does not work in PHP, you should investigate the PHP code. Show us how you call the procedrue from PHP. As for the procedire code itself, note that the query against `information_schema.columns` should be limited to correct `TABLE_SCHEMA` as multiple databases may have a table with same name.

Comment: @slaakso yes, thanks for the advice. I have updated the original question so you can see how I call procedure from PHP - It enter where `$resp->esito = 20;`

Comment: I'm not sure.. but try the following: Remove `;` from the query. Remove `$stmt->close();` and `$conn->close();`. You can "close" them later, after you have processed the data/result.

Answer (score 0):

Cursors and prepared statements do not play well together. You can use MySQLi's `query`-method instead:

```
$table = $conn->real_escape_string($id_datatable);
$sql = "CALL aw_spZAAAOttieniDataTables('$table')";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // Loop through the rows
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // handle the $row
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, It seems to work. Should I worry about SQL Injection?

Comment: if you have the character set correctly set then you are ok. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php.

Comment: "Cursors and prepared statements do not play well together" - I can't think of a reason. Do you have any reference?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel. No. When I have tried to execute a stored procedure with a cursor + another query using prepare+execute, have not been able get past the cursor execution in order to reach the query. Happy to be proven wrong. mysqli::query ( (and mysqli::multi_query) works without problems.